# Не понял прикола

Tags: значение-слов

На Грамоте почему-то нету слова ***террариум.***

Comment: Артём, а в чем именно суть вопроса?

Comment: Ну интересно, почему такого распространённого слова нету в словаре, Иван. ;) Хотя бы предположения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

См.:

**[террарий](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x)** =====================

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во как! Спасибо, Слава!